# Logback throwing ConcurrentModificationException on exiting program inside docker container

Tags: java, docker, logback, concurrentmodification, spring-logback

My application is throwing ConcurrentModificationException when it is trying to exit the program.It is using a standard Logback configuration. This works fine when running as a standalone java application but throws the exception when trying to run inside a docker container. The stack trace is as below:

```
Exception in thread "Logback shutdown hook [default]" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1043)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:997)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.fireOnReset(LoggerContext.java:323)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.reset(LoggerContext.java:226)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.stop(LoggerContext.java:348)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.hook.ShutdownHookBase.stop(ShutdownHookBase.java:39)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook.run(DelayingShutdownHook.java:57)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I am using a standard Logback configuration file through logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
    <!--See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html -->
    <shutdownHook
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <appender name="CONSOLE_JSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
                <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                    <!-- <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint> -->
                </jsonFormatter>
                <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX</timestampFormat>
                <includeContextName>false</includeContextName>
                <appendLineSeparator>true</appendLineSeparator>
            </layout>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ASYNCSTDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <queueSize>5000</queueSize> <!-- Default is 256 -->
        <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold> <!-- Instruction to drop events
            once the buffer reaches the max capacity. Default value is 20%.
            20 means drop lower event when has 20% capacity remaining -->
        <neverBlock>true</neverBlock><!-- default false. Setting it to true to
            cause the Appender not block the application and just drop the messages -->
        <maxFlushTime>5000</maxFlushTime> <!-- The default maximum queue flush time allowed during appender stop. If
            the worker takes longer than this time it will exit, discarding any remaining
            cartItems in the queue -->
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_JSON"/>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNCSTDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

The artifacts I am using in my pom are as below:

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <dependencies>
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.14</version>
        </dependency>
       
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
```